# Are there any docs for MySQLOData?

Tags: php, mysql, odata

I am trying to install and use MySQLOData (OData service for MySQL DB Servers): http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqlodata/

However I cannot find any documentation on how to install it or use it!

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look here ! http://mirror.transact.net.au/pub/sourceforge/m/project/my/mysqlodata/0.1.1-alpha/MySQLOData%20Manual.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You can find a manual within a previous version of mysqlodata (0.1.1) on this page: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqlodata/files/0.1.1-alpha/